# android app and realtime message with Meteor

Tags: meteor

I am learning meteor and making simple chat app then this question hit my mind..

If I am making web app then that is fine because all the user will access from save server and database but what about mobile users..

Lets say I am making android app and I want to build it.. When I build the app will it give me `Mongo` database along with `apk` or I have to install it manually ?

Second i can think of its do everything in the same database and just make browser for the app..

But what I want to store per user data in their mobile.. that is no related to my database ?

In my chat app in the browser it is working in realtime but what If i build and make `apk` for android with different database ..

I just want to know what would be the best approach if I am making a messaging app ? I am confused on `database` .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The database is always remote MongoDB on the server where your server code runs.

For example your server address is http://someserver.com. This is where you publically deploy your application.

While building the apk, you need to specify the --mobile-server attribute which tells your mobile application where to point for server code and database.

If you host your database on some MongoDB hosting providers like [compose.io](http://compose.io) then you need to specify MONGO_URL environment variable while building.

To cut it short, MongoDB is neither on apk nor on client (they have something called minimongo on client which is definitely not your actual database) but it is on the server where you have hosted your application.

Good Luck!